# Array to string conversion PHP is showing error

Tags: sql, database, pdo, insert

Hey guys I am trying to update a checkbox feild in my database and have to capture and bind the Values in using SQL PDO.

I am getting an error however about an array to string conversion,

my check boxes look like this -

```
<div class="checkboxFour">


<p class="admin_label" id="checklabel2">In Seaon</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inSeason[]" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" checked="checked"<?php if( isset( $_GET['inSeason'] ) ){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>
                <label for="checkboxFourInput"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkboxFour">
                <p class= "admin_label"id="checklabel2">Out Season</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inSeason[]" value="0" id="checkboxFour2Input" <?php if( isset( $_GET['inSeason'] ) ){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
                <label for="checkboxFour2Input"></label>
            </div>
```

In my PHP I have built the following -

```
if (isset($_POST['updateProductSubmit'])) {
 // open the database connection
 include 'includes/connection.php';


$inSeasonValue = "0";
if( array_key_exists( 'inSeason', $_GET ) && $_GET['inSeason'] == '0' ){
    $saleItemValue = "0";
    echo $saleItemValue['inSeason'];
}

$inSeasonValue = "1";
if( array_key_exists( 'inSeason', $_GET ) && $_GET['inSeason'] == '1' ){
    $saleItemValue = "1";
    echo $saleItemValue['inSeason'];
}


try {
 //create our sql update statement
 $sql = "UPDATE Products SET productNbr = :productNbr, productName= :productName, inSeason = '$inSeasonValue', description = :description, photo =
 :photo WHERE productNbr=:productNbr;";

 // prepare the statement
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 // bind the values

  $statement->bindValue(':productNbr', $_POST['productNbr']);
  $statement->bindValue(':productName', $_POST['productName']);
  $statement->bindValue(':inSeason', $_POST['inSeason']);
  $statement->bindValue(':description', $_POST['description']);
  $statement->bindValue(':photo', $_POST['photo']);


 // execute the statement
 $success = $statement->execute();
 } // end try

 catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'Error updating item: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit();
 } // end catch

 // test the result and display appropriate message
 if ($success) {

 echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Successfully updated Item.")</script>';
 }
 else {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Unable to execute the Item update.");</script>';
 }
 //free connection to the server
 $statement->closeCursor();
 } // end if statement
 ?>
```

The error is pointing out that the bind value  `$statement->bindValue(':inSeason', $_POST['inSeason']);`

I hope you guys can help!!

Thanks so Much in advance!!

:-)

Comment: Using the square-bracket-name-suffix notation, ie `name="inSeason[]"` causes PHP to interpret the POST data value as an array, hence the array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

You have named your `inSeason` checkox with an array construct here

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inSeason[]" value="0" id="checkboxFour2Input" <?php if( isset( $_GET['inSeason'] ) ){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
```

This will appear as an array when PHP decodes th $_GET data, but here

```
if( array_key_exists( 'inSeason', $_GET ) && $_GET['inSeason'] == '0' ){
```

You're testing against a string, hence the array-to-sring error message.

Simply rename your checkBox in your HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inSeason" value="0" id="checkboxFour2Input" <?php if( isset( $_GET['inSeason'] ) ){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
                                    ^^^ remove square brackets here.
```

Comment: thanks so much mike that got rid of my error ok :-) can you see anything wrong with how I am inserting the value in the sql statement? or binding the value, all is updating bar the inSeason col.